# Convert old Rspec syntax into new syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using the [APIonRails tutorial](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_two) and they have this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApiConstraints do
  let(:api_constraints_v1) { ApiConstraints.new(version: 1) }
  let(:api_constraints_v2) { ApiConstraints.new(version: 2, default: true) }

  describe "matches?" do

    it "returns true when the version matches the 'Accept' header" do
      request = double(host: 'api.marketplace.dev',
                       headers: {"Accept" => "application/vnd.marketplace.v1"})
      api_constraints_v1.matches?(request).should be_true
    end

    it "returns the default version when 'default' option is specified" do
      request = double(host: 'api.marketplace.dev')
      api_constraints_v2.matches?(request).should be_true
    end
  end
end
```

In an example, but I have come to understand that this is using the old syntax.

To convert this into the new syntax, I am trying this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ApiConstraints do
  let(:api_constraints_v1) { ApiConstraints.new(version: 1) }
  let(:api_constraints_v2) { ApiConstraints.new(version: 2, default: true) }

  describe "matches?" do
    it "returns true when the version matches the 'Accept' header" do
      request = double(host: 'api.localhost:3000',
                headers: {"Accept" => "application/vnd.marketplace.v1"})
      expect(request).to match(api_constraints_v1)
    end

    it "returns the default version when 'default' option is specified" do
      request = double(host: 'api.localhost:3000')
      expect api_constraints_v2.matches?(request).to_be true
    end
  end

end
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Failures:

  1) ApiConstraints matches? returns true when the version matches the 'Accept' header
     Failure/Error: expect(request).to match(api_constraints_v1)
       expected #<RSpec::Mocks::Double:0x3feeedaf60c4 @name=nil> to match #<ApiConstraints:0x007fddde50f9b0 @version=1, @default=nil>
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -#<ApiConstraints:0x007fddde50f9b0 @default=nil, @version=1>
       +#<RSpec::Mocks::Double:0x3feeedaf60c4 @name=nil>

     # ./lib/spec/api_constraints_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) ApiConstraints matches? returns the default version when 'default' option is specified
     Failure/Error: expect api_constraints_v2.matches?(request).to_be true
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to_be' for true:TrueClass
       Did you mean?  to_enum
                      to_s
     # ./lib/spec/api_constraints_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.0045 seconds (files took 6.52 seconds to load)
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./lib/spec/api_constraints_spec.rb:8 # ApiConstraints matches? returns true when the version matches the 'Accept' header
rspec ./lib/spec/api_constraints_spec.rb:14 # ApiConstraints matches? returns the default version when 'default' option is specified
```

What could be causing this?

**Edit 1**

Per My `Gemfile.lock`, these are the versions of my relevant gems:

```
rspec (3.1.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.1.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.1.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.1.0)
rspec-core (3.1.7)
  rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
rspec-expectations (3.1.2)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
rspec-mocks (3.1.3)
  rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
rspec-rails (3.1.0)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.1.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.1.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.1.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
rspec-support (3.1.2)
rubyzip (1.2.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.53.0)
  childprocess (~> 0.5)
  rubyzip (~> 1.0)
  websocket (~> 1.0)
shellany (0.0.1)
shoulda (3.5.0)
  shoulda-context (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
  shoulda-matchers (>= 1.4.1, < 3.0)
shoulda-context (1.2.1)
shoulda-matchers (2.8.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
```

What is the correct new syntax I should use to be able to achieve the same thing that the original code achieves?

Comment: `expect request.to eq(api_constraints_v1)` -> `expect(request).to eq(api_constraints_v1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the original test change

```
api_constraints_v1.matches?(request).should be_true
```

to

```
expect(api_constraints_v1.matches?(request)).to be_truthy
```

or

```
expect(api_constraints_v1.matches?(request)).to be(true)
```

if you expect only a boolean value to be returned.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks much!

Comment: For converting a lot of old syntax specs I highly recommend using [transpec](https://github.com/yujinakayama/transpec).

Answer (score 1):

change

```
expect request.to eq(api_constraints_v1)
```

to

```
expect(request).to eq(api_constraints_v1)
```

and the same problem in the other spec...

`expect` is a method to which you give the thing that the expectation is going on (ie `request`)...

after you get the result from the `request` method - you then call `to` on it...

The way you had it before... you are *first* calling `to` on `request` and *then* passing the result of that to `expect`... ie, grouping matters ;)

Comment: Well I guess the real question is, is: `expect(request).to be(api_constraints_v1)` the same thing as: `api_constraints_v1.matches?(request).should be_true`. I doubt it is.

What's the new syntax version of the old syntax expectation?

Comment: Adding parentheses: `(api_constraints_v1.matches?(request)).should be_true` (while not best practice for the old should) shows more clearly which part is given to `should` (and therefore which part kind of then goes to `expect`). In this case (assuming that your API constraint is always a regex), you could probably change it to `expect(request).to match(api_constraints_v1)` Note: you will always use parentheses with the `expect` syntax. They aren't optional.

Comment: There's more detail on the `match` matcher in the docs here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/match-matcher

Comment: I like where you are going Taryn, but it doesn't quite fully help me here. For instance, I tried your latter suggestion and this is the error I get now: `Failure/Error: expect(request).to match(api_constraints_v1)
       expected #<RSpec::Mocks::Double:0x3fc4751b8504 @name=nil> to match #<ApiConstraints:0x007f88ea370148 @version=1, @default=nil>
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -#<ApiConstraints:0x007f88ea370148 @default=nil, @version=1>
       +#<RSpec::Mocks::Double:0x3fc4751b8504 @name=nil>       
     # /spec/api_constraints_spec.rb:11:in block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'`

Comment: yes, like I said... it only works if your `api_constraints_v1` is a regex (or string). just like `matches?` would have ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same `ApiConstraints` in my [rails-api-base](https://github.com/jordifierro/rails-api-base) project and it crashes when you try `matches?` with a non-default version without specifying the `Accept` header.

I added the following test (which crashes):

```
it 'returns false when not default and no Accept header' do
  request = double(host: 'api.marketplace.dev')
  expect(api_constraints_v1.matches?(request)).to be false
end
```

And I fixed `ApiConstraints`:

```
def matches?(req)
  @default ||
    (req.respond_to?('headers') &&
     req.headers.key?('Accept') &&
     req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.marketplace.v#{@version}"))
end
```

Hope it helps!